# Data Type error while appending suffix in numpy nd array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
x=np.array([['A',1,'Q'],['B',2,'W'],['B',3,'E'],['C',4,'R']])
```

x is an numpy array. I am trying the below operation but it gives me the error

```
x[x[:,0]=='B',0] = x[x[:,0]=='B',0] + 'V'
```

> UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature
> matching types (dtype('<U11'), dtype('<U1')) -> None

I am trying to append some suffix in col1 where my condition is true in rows.

Please help

Thanks,
Liva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [841]: x=np.array([['A',1,'Q'],['B',2,'W'],['B',3,'E'],['C',4,'R']])
In [842]: x
Out[842]: 
array([['A', '1', 'Q'],
       ['B', '2', 'W'],
       ['B', '3', 'E'],
       ['C', '4', 'R']], dtype='<U21')
In [843]: mask = x[:,0]=='B'
In [844]: mask
Out[844]: array([False,  True,  True, False])
In [845]: x[mask,0]
Out[845]: array(['B', 'B'], dtype='<U21')
```

`np.char` has functions that can apply Python string methods to arrays:

```
In [846]: np.char.add(x[mask,0],'V')
Out[846]: array(['BV', 'BV'], dtype='<U22')
In [847]: x[mask,0]=_
In [848]: x
Out[848]: 
array([['A', '1', 'Q'],
       ['BV', '2', 'W'],
       ['BV', '3', 'E'],
       ['C', '4', 'R']], dtype='<U21')
```

Alternatively we could make an object dtype array, that contains Python strings.

```
In [849]: X = x.astype(object)
In [850]: X
Out[850]: 
array([['A', '1', 'Q'],
       ['BV', '2', 'W'],
       ['BV', '3', 'E'],
       ['C', '4', 'R']], dtype=object)
In [851]: X[mask,0]
Out[851]: array(['BV', 'BV'], dtype=object)
In [852]: X[mask,0]+'V'   # string plus works here
Out[852]: array(['BVV', 'BVV'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you. One question, What is the difference between object dtype array and normal array and which one is better in performance for large dataset

Comment: Performance doing what?  Math on object dtype arrays is slower,and hit-of-miss (compared to numeric dtype).  But for strings, I suspect they are similar.  `numpy` doesn't have any special string code, so even the `np.char` functions depend on python code.  `pandas` sticks with object dtype.

Comment: Thanks. The problem I posted here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68478259/very-slow-numpy-or-operation)  is because of dtype object or it is numpy expected behavior. Much appreciated if you can look at it .