# Very slow numpy OR operation

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am doing an OR operation on large dataset which is an numpy dtype array object.

Below code is part of outer FOR loop which goes through 15 columns and check if username is available in any of those columns and if yes then flag those rows for further operation.

```
mask= mask | (np_array[:,col_index[f"COL_{col_number}"]] == username)
```

mask= Numpy one dimension array of same length as np_array
np_array = Numpy dtype ndarray object

This line of code consume more than 60 % of my overall code time.

Any way we can improve/optimize the above code performance ?

Thanks,
Liva

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example so we can help better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alist = [(np_array[:,col_index[f"COL_{col_number}"]] == username) for col_number in range(columns)]
```

this should be a list of all the col_number tests

```
mask = np.logical_or.reduce(alist)
```

should `or` them together.  Performance should be better than repeatedly `or`ing.  But I wouldn't surprised if the `alist` construction is the slowest step.

But without a working example, I can't test or time this.